# How to Name TTF Properly

Tags: windows, fonts, truetype

I am having trouble with something that appears to be trivial, namely how to name a font, so that I get multiple styles of the same font to tile, display nicely, import nicely using `Inno Script Studio`, work with C#, not to mention applications.

For instance, here is an Adobe font that work nicely, first what I see in Control Panel, then the TTF details. I will then show what I did with my font and how I do not see the exact same thing, even though I did seemingly the same thing.

Adobe Source Sans Pro Tiles

[image: Adobe Source Sans Pro Tiles in Windows Control Panel]

Adobe Source Sans Pro Details

[image: Adobe Source Sans Pro Details]

Adobe Source Sans Pro Semibold: The purpose of a screenshot is to show what I see from the actual TTF using `Birdfont` font editor, plus version.

[image: Adobe Source Sans Pro Semibold Naming Details]

Here is the black:

```
PostScript Name: SourceSansPro-Black
Name:            Source Sans Pro
Style:           Black
Full Name:       Source Sans Pro Black
```

Here is how I named the font that I am using on my project. The font name, `Venera`, is the font family and then these are the styles: `100 Extra Light`, `300 Light`, `500 Medium`, `700 Bold`, and `900 Black`.

BTW, I tried with the numbers, without the numbers, with spaces, and no spaces. There was no combination that worked like what I see with the Adobe font.

```
PostScript Name: Venera-900Black
Name:            Venera
Style:           900 Black
Full Name:       Venera 900 Black
```

Here is the bold:

```
PostScript Name: Venera-700Bold
Name:            Venera
Style:           700 Bold
Full Name:       Venera 700 Bold
```

I did think that maybe styles cannot have embedded spaces, so I tried both `700Bold` / `900Black` as the `Style` and even just `Bold` / `Black`. The latter was my thought that Windows does not support numbers s part of style names.

What I see is the fonts not overlapping like Adobe, but stacked. One has to delete the TOP font to see that there is a font underneath. Needless to say, Word in such a case does not see both fonts.

Here is what I see after I install the `700 Bold` bold font and then the `900 Black` font. I took this screenshot after installing the `700 Bold` style and before installing the `900 Black` style, but the image is identical to what I see after `900 Black`. The order makes no difference, I have to delete one font to see the other. The fonts are not stacked like what I see with Adobe. Restarting the computer makes no difference. Removing the numbers or spaces make no difference.

Image with BOTH fonts, just one would never know it from the screenshot.

[image: Both fonts are there just not stacked like in Adobe]

I suspect that when I get this first part working that Inno Script wants the full name and not the `font name` as stated in the help material and pages here in SO, but first things first. I need to get the font behaving.

For whatever it is worth, I can set the style to `Regular` and then set the font name to: `Venera700Bold` and `Venera900Black`. I would then wind up with two different fonts that show `Venera700Bold Regular` and `Venera900Black Regular` in Control Panel. `Inno Script Studio` is then quite happy accepting `Venera700Bold` and `Venera900Black` as the font name in the `Files` section.

It is tempting to use this answer, but all the fonts are the same family and I would really rather do things the right way and not subject users to different fonts, especially when I have 7 different Avenir fonts that I have to do the same thing for.

The answer should be `Font Name` is alphanumeric with however many spaces. The style is alphanumeric with however many spaces. The full name, as the editor says is the concatenation of the font name and style. The unique name and PostScript name must have no spaces and have the style separated from the font name by a dash. Sadly, this recipe, which works for others, such as the Adobe font that I picked at random, does not work for me, so I am missing a piece to the puzzle in my understanding.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The style names should not include the numeric weight values. The numeric values should only go into the font's 'OS/2' table, not in the name strings. If you include the numbers in the style string, then the OS or apps will probably get confused, treating the number as part of the family name.

If you tried just using "Bold", "Black" as the style names and that's not working, then I would suspect the tool used to create the fonts.